# Select columns in a data frame with Negative Values

Tags: r, apply, sapply

How to select columns in data frame with negative values. For below data frame, want to select column x, y and z

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(-2,3,4), y = c(2,1,-5), z = c(1,-5,6), a = c(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some other ways :

1. `colSums` :

```
data[colSums(data < 0) > 0]

#   x  y  z
#1 -2  2  1
#2  3  1 -5
#3  4 -5  6
```

2. `Filter` :

```
Filter(function(x) any(x < 0), data)
```

3. `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%  select(where(~any(. < 0)))
#select_if if you have older version
#data %>%  select_if(~any(. < 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is using sapply and apply functions in R

x<- data[!sapply(apply(data, 2, function(w){ if(min(w)<0) return(list(w)) }), is.null)]

names(x)

Feel free to suggest other ways of doing so

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

```
data[, sapply(1:ncol(data), function(i) any(data[, i] < 0))]
```

or to use `purrr`:

```
data %>% purrr::keep(~any(. < 0))

data %>% purrr::discard(~!any(. < 0))
```

which will yield:

```
#    x  y  z
# 1 -2  2  1
# 2  3  1 -5
# 3  4 -5  6
```

Comment: That'd be the approach I'd go with, but you can just `sapply` over `data` directly without needing the subsetting - `sapply(data, function(i) any(i < 0) )`

Answer (score 0):

`data[apply(data, 2, function(col) any(col < 0))]`

- `any(expr)` returns true when the `expr` holds true for any element in a vector/list.
- `apply(x, margin, fun)`, where `margin = 2` means vectorise over columns

Answer (score 0):

You can do a vector with the colnames which contain negative values and then select them, example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Dataset demo
data <- data.frame(
  letter=c("A", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  positive=c(.26,.25,.36,.11,.35),
  negative=c(12,15,-1,-10,-12)
)

# Vector with colnames with negative values
vector_negative <- colnames(data)[colSums(data < 0)]

# Select from de dataframe
data %>%
 select(all_of(vector_negative))
```

Output:

```
 negative
1       12
2       15
3       -1
4      -10
5      -12
```